# How to join 2 table without duplicating data

Tags: php, arrays, database, multidimensional-array

I need help with the following,

I want to code this out

```
  Array ( [0] => 1 [duration] => 1 [1] => Singapore [ai_Name] => Singapore )
  {"duration":"1","ai_Name":"Singapore"}
```

but I am getting this instead

```
   Array ( [0] => 1 [duration] => 1 [1] => Singapore [ai_Name] => Singapore )
  {"0":"1","duration":"1","1":"Singapore","ai_Name":"Singapore"}
```

below is my code

```html
<?php
      require 'dbfunction.php';
      $id = $_GET['staffid'];
      $con = getDBConnect();
   
        if(!mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
            $sqlQueryStr =  "SELECT r.duration, a.ai_Name " .
                            "FROM report r " .
                            "JOIN academicinstitution a ON r.ai_Id = a.ai_Id " .
                            "WHERE staff_Id = '$id' ";

            $result = mysqli_query($con,$sqlQueryStr);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            mysqli_close($con);
      } else {
         echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

        print_r($row);
        echo '<br>';
        $json = json_encode($row);
        echo $json;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you get a mixed array as result, an indexed and an associative array. Use [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) instead of `mysqli_fetch_array()`:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sqlQueryStr);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
var_dump($row);
```

will return

```
Array ( [duration] => 1 [ai_Name] => Singapore )
```

which will be parsed to

```
{"duration":"1","ai_Name":"Singapore"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using  `GROUP BY`

More info here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-handling.html